# Possible to reverse a css animation on class removal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Essentially what I'm trying to do is give an element a CSS animation when it gains a class, then reverse that animation when I remove the class **without playing the animation when the DOM renders**.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bmh5g/

As you can see in the fiddle, when you hover the "Hover Me" button, `#item` flips down. When you mouseoff the hover button, `#item` just disappears. I want `#item` to flip back up (ideally using the same animation but in reverse). Is this possible?

```js
$('#trigger').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('#item').addClass('flipped');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('#item').removeClass('flipped');
  }
})
```

```css
#item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#item.flipped {
  animation: flipper 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: flipper 0.7s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes flipper {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  33% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipper {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='trigger'>Hover Me</div>
<div id='item'></div>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would have the `#item` start out hidden with the reverse animation by default. Then add the class to give it the animation and show the `#item`. http://jsfiddle.net/bmh5g/12/

```js
$('#trigger').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('#item').show();
    $('#item').addClass('flipped');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('#item').removeClass('flipped');
  }
});
```

```css
#trigger {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  animation: flipperUp 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: flipperUp 0.7s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#item.flipped {
  animation: flipper 0.7s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation: flipper 0.7s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes flipper {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  33% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipper {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes flipperUp {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  33% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(10deg);
  }
  66% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipperUp {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(10deg);
  }
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='trigger'>Hover Me</div>
<div id='item'></div>
```

Comment: Best answer thus far - I don't think it's possible to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 10):

### In addition to the answers here, please cache your `$(selector)`

So you pretty much do this `var elements = $(selector);` to cache.

Why?! Because if you use the code in the answers on this page as is you will ask the DOM for that same element collection (`$('#item')`) each time. DOM reading is an expensive operation.

For example, the accepted answer would look something like so:

```
var item = $('#item');
$('#trigger').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        item.show();
        item.addClass('flipped');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        item.removeClass('flipped');
    }
});
```

### Since I've written all this text, might as well answer your question using CSS transitions

I know you asked for a CSS animations example, but for the animation you wanted to do (a card flipping open), it can be easily achieved using CSS transitions:

```css
#item {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
}

#item+div {
  width: 70px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: perspective(250px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out
}

#item:hover+div {
  transform: perspective(250px) rotateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="item"></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Another approach, rather than using `display: none`, is to suppress the reverse animation with a class on page load, and then remove that class with the same event that applies the normal animation (eg: flipper). Like so (http://jsfiddle.net/astrotim/d7omcbrz/1/):

**CSS - in addition to the flipperUp keyframe posted by Blake above**

```
#item.no-animation 
{
  animation: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#trigger').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $('#item').removeClass('no-animation');
        $('#item').addClass('flipped');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $('#item').removeClass('flipped');
    }
})
```

Comment: Good solution when `#item` should be displayed all the time, but only animated after some event, e.g. `:hover`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the attribute `animation-direction` to run the same animation in reverse.
If you couple this with one of the many methods described [here](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) for restarting an animation- we can start the animation forwards on `mouseenter`, then on `mouseleave` we can restart it and play it in reverse.

I don't know how to use jQuery very well, so I chose one of the non-jQuery methods mentioned in the article.

```
const element_button = document.getElementById('trigger');
const element_item = document.getElementById('item');

element_button.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  if (element_item.classList.contains('animate-backwards')) {
    element_item.classList.remove('animate-backwards');
    void element_item.offsetWidth;
  }
  
  element_item.classList.add('animate-forwards');
});

element_button.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  element_item.classList.remove('animate-forwards');
  void element_item.offsetWidth;
  
  element_item.classList.add('animate-backwards');
});
```

and

```
#item.animate-forwards {
  animation: flipper 0.7s normal;
  -webkit-animation: flipper 0.7s normal;
  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#item.animate-backwards {
  animation: flipper 0.7s reverse;
  -webkit-animation: flipper 0.7s reverse;
  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hq13L8bz/) for the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Its animating down using css so to get it to animate up you need to create a class, say .item-up that does the transformation in the opposite so then you would remove the previous class and add the item-up class and that should animate it up.

I would write you a js fiddle for it but I dont know the syntax well enough.

Basically when you will need:

```
@keyframes flipper
@keyframes flipper-up  //This does the opposite of flipper
```

and

```
$('#trigger').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $('#item').removeClass('flipped-up');
        $('#item').addClass('flipped');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $('#item').removeClass('flipped');
        $('#item').addClass('flipped-up');
    }
})
```

[jsfiddle.net/bmh5g/3](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh5g/3)  courtesy of Jake

Comment: The problem I see with this method is that I don't like the unpredictability of having an element with two classes that both have animations, simultaneously. What happens if I mouse onto the element, and mouseoff before it's finished?

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmh5g/3/

This works decently well, except that if you continuously hover on and off, it disappears.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the jsfiddle.

Comment: I feel what makes this question interesting is if there was a way to do it without simply making another class.

Comment: @aug - Yes, that is what I would really like (and it seems as though something like that should be possible, given the ideologies of CSS)

Comment: I don't think you can with keyframes, but without keyframes it works just fine, but you can't get the animations you get with keyframes -> http://jsfiddle.net/bmh5g/10/

Comment: @adeneo Yeah, that's what I'm doing right now in lieu of the prettier animations. It's too bad this isn't just the default behavior of animations...

Comment: IMOO, `$("#item").toggleClass("flipped-up flipped");` in every mouse evt handlers would be better

Answer (score 0):

CSS solution from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and almost supported by all browser

.animation(animationName 10s ease-in-out infinite alternate both running;)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write the opposite CSS animation to undo visuals.

```css
/* --- Flipped --- */

.flipped {
  animation: PlayFlip 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes PlayFlip {
  to {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

/* --- Unflipped --- */

.unflipped {
  animation: PlayUnflip 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes PlayUnflip {
  from {
    /* Ensure this stays consistent with PlayFlip! */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
```

Then, in your code, set the class to "flipped" when the flipping activates and "unflipped" when the flipping deactivates.

Answer (score -2):

Worked fo me:
1 animation in reverse for the Element (from 100% to 0%)
1 separate animation forwards for the new class (from 0% to 100%)
And toggling that class would work

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/q7bc4s0f/17/
```

Upd:
That way animation will play backwards on page load. To solve this you have to ADD new bacwards animation class on event ONCE and then toggle forwards animation class on that event.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).