# Clicking a button to initiate an animation, then clicking another button to revers that animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a button where you can click it. It then initiates a CSS animation where some buttons and text flow down the screen saying are you sure you want to do this? They can then click the yes or no button and I want it to reverse the animation back up. I have completed the animation going down but I can't manage to repeat that animation going back up when they click a button.

Here is the HTML:

```
<button onclick="confirm()">Delete</button>

<div id="wholeshow" class="confirm-whole">
    <h1 class="confirm">Delete</h1>
    <p class="confirm">Are you sure you want to delete ____?</p>
    <button class="confirm" onclick="reset()">Delete</button>
    <button class="confirm" onclick="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
function confirm() {

document.getElementById("wholeshow").classList.add("add");
}
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.confirm-whole {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    animation: slideIn 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIn {

    0% {
        top: -250px;
        height: 0%;
    }

    99% {
        height: 0%;
    }

    100% {
        top: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.add {
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to reverse a css animation on class removal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023859/possible-to-reverse-a-css-animation-on-class-removal)

Comment: Do you want to go back to `display: none` again after pressing `confirm-whole`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript isn't pretty but it works, perhaps a better solution would be to use CSS transitions if they are able to support your animation requirements.

```js
function confirm() {
  document.getElementById("wholeshow").classList.add("add");
}

// added
function reset() {
  const wholeshow = document.getElementById("wholeshow");
  const resetDir = () => { // need to reset the animation direction and remove the `add` class
    wholeshow.removeEventListener("animationend", resetDir, true);
    wholeshow.style.animationDirection = "normal";
    wholeshow.classList.remove("add");
  };

  wholeshow.addEventListener("animationend", resetDir, true);
  wholeshow.style.animationDirection = "reverse";
  wholeshow.classList.remove("add");
  void wholeshow.offsetWidth; // force rerender
  wholeshow.classList.add("add");
}
```

```css
.confirm-whole {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  animation: slideIn 0.5s;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    top: -250px;
    height: 0%;
  }
  99% {
    height: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.add {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="confirm()">Delete</button>

<div id="wholeshow" class="confirm-whole">
  <h1 class="confirm">Delete</h1>
  <p class="confirm">Are you sure you want to delete ____?</p>
  <button class="confirm" onclick="reset()">Delete</button>
  <button class="confirm" onclick="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```