# Toggle slide fade out, slide fade (back) in with CSS Keyframes and React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a box (div) that I would like to toggle with slide-out animation and then slide-back in animation (the exact reverse) on button press.

I do not want any animations on initial page render. I am able to successfully slide the box left/fade-out of the page on button press, however the slide back in does not have any transition or animation.

How do I add this transition when the element comes back into view without adding a class that will fire with initial page render?

**SlideBoxApp.js**

```
class SlideBoxApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        slideIn: false
    }
  }
  
  toggleSlide() {
    const { slideIn } = this.state
    this.setState({slideIn: !slideIn})
  }
  
  render() {
    const { slideIn } = this.state
      return (
        <div>
         <button onClick={() => this.toggleSlide()}>slide in</button>
         <div className={`box ${slideIn? 'slideLeft' : ''}`}></div>
        </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SlideBoxApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

**SlideBoxApp.css**

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.slideLeft {
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-name: slideLeft;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.slideRight {
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-name: slideLeft;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fq2pkmuL/32/)

Comment: Also check this thread about the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023859/possible-to-reverse-a-css-animation-on-class-removal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the slide back in does not have any transition or animation

I've searched for a solution to animate the element back to its original state after a `keyframe` is removed, and wasn't able to find one.
Having a `keyframe` means an animation between **start** and **end** states, so initial page animation is inevitable if you want to animate both *in* and *out*.

However, you could achieve your desired result with just `transition` instead of `keyframes`.
Just add the new state in `.slideLeft` class:

```css
.slideLeft {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

And give the `.box` some `transition` properties:

```css
.box {
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
```

I updated your [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pxL4y1o/).